# HeadlessUI/vue: TypeError vue.defineComponent is not a function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I try to install `@headlessui/vue` in my `nuxt` project.

When I try to use it like:

```html
<template>
  <Menu>
    <MenuItems>
      <MenuItem>Item</MenuItem>
    </MenuItems>
  </Menu>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItems, MenuItem } from '@headlessui/vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  components: { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItems, MenuItem },
  data () {
    return {
      isScrolling: false
    }
  },
....
```

I get a type error while compiling

```
TypeError
vue.defineComponent is not a function
```

Comment: The library stated that it only supports vue3 while nuxt is still using vue 2.6.12 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@headlessui/vue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exactly the same question here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/31

> This library is created for Vue 3. I am not sure that NuxtJS is using Vue 3, I think they are using Vue 2. Can you verify this?

> Yep Nuxt hasn’t released a version on Vue 3 yet but as far as I understand a beta is coming in the near future

Comment: Hi, this has been around for a while, but I'm still getting this error with Nuxt. Is there a way to fix? I'm using chartjs vue wrapper with Nuxt and getting this error

Comment: @CornelVerster this is unrelated to HeadlessUI. I've answered you on your [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71913165/vue-chartjs-and-nuxt-vue-definecomponent-is-not-a-function#comment127076762_71913165).