# NuxtJS & Tailwind UI

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I've just tried to install fresh nuxtjs app with tailwindcss and tailwind ui component and got some errors. After some research I found out that @headlessui/vue and @heroicons/vue supports Vue 3 only. NuxtJS is based on Vue 2 :(

Is there any possible way to use Vue 3 in NuxtJS? NuxtJS 3 with Vue 3 was announced, but the roadmap for that was announced in November 2020, but there is no information about the release.

NuxtJS fits perfectly to our needs, so it would be great if we could use it somehow.

Do someone have any ideas?

Comment: No. You cannot use Vue 3 with Nuxt v2 (current stable, latest). The entire core engine is built around Vue 2 and is undergoing an entire rewrite to support Vue 3 in Nuxt 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the HeadlessUI part, the answer was already given a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67540286/8816585

Nuxt3 is really close to ship, probably at the end of the month or in the one to follow. If you want to keep updated, you can subscribe to this [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6467#issuecomment-844126711) or simply follow the co-founder @Atinux on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Atinux).

You could try using [@nuxtjs/composition-api](https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api) to have access to the composition API but even with this, I'm not sure that this will work properly (or/and will be easy to use).

The best call as of right now, use Nuxt v2 with latest TailwindCSS v2.

The migration should not be that hard from 2 to 3. Also, HeadlessUI is something that you will not have access to as of right now IMO (maybe there are some packages that do handle the use of it but they will probably break/not be working so great).
Try using you own components or import a small UI library with only the JS logic. And remove it once Nuxt3 is here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried the composition API, but failed... So I've tried NextJS for which is TailwindCSS / UI also made with the necessary components (heroicons & headlessui) and it works like a charm. So now I learn NextJS and React :)

Comment: nuxt 3 super slow, very much disappointed, waited since 2019

Comment: @LIHOTAN not sure where and with which configuration you tried this. Can you elaborate?